# Can a spellcaster use Mage Hand to trigger a trap?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, traps

Could you use Mage Hand to trigger a trap, at least sometimes? Based on [this well reasoned answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68831/60557) you cannot use Mage Hand to disable the trap, but [Unseen Servant can trigger](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/160717/60557) some traps. For example, if the trap is a thin wire Mage Hand should be able to grab it. Likewise if a trap triggered by opening a chest, if Mage Hand can open the chest the trap should trigger. Since Mage Hand cannot pick locks those kinds of traps remain off limits, as do any traps that require significant amounts to weight to trigger. As 5E focuses on rulings not rules this is not about the DC for triggering a trap, only if it is possible with Mage Hand. Many have already weighted in on other questions about the 5E dislike to trying to roll for everything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [If Mage Hand triggers the trap.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/running-the-game)

> Most traps are triggered when a creature goes somewhere or touches something that the trap's creator wanted to protect. Common triggers include stepping on a pressure plate or a false section of floor, pulling a trip wire, turning a doorknob, and using the wrong key in a lock. Magic traps are often set to go off when a creature enters an area or touches an object. Some magic traps (such as the glyph of warding spell) have more complicated trigger conditions, including a password that prevents the trap from activating.

Trap triggers can be whatever your game master wants, including actions you can do with mage hand, or simply the presence of magic itself.

Of course, it is up to your game master if the pressure of Mage Hand isn't enough to trigger the trap. For example, a pit trap or a wire trap may require you to lift more than ten pounds.

The rules for [Mage Hand are as such.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand)

> A spectral, floating hand appears at a point you choose within range. The hand lasts for the duration or until you dismiss it as an action. The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 feet away from you or if you cast this spell again.

> You can use your action to control the hand. You can use the hand to manipulate an object, open an unlocked door or container, stow or retrieve an item from an open container, or pour the contents out of a vial. You can move the hand up to 30 feet each time you use it.

> The hand can't attack, activate magic items, or carry more than 10 pounds.

There are several limitations.

Comment: Good answer. It might be insightful to highlight some of the limitations described in the spell. At a glance, I see that it can hold up to 10lb, so I would assume it could not press on a pressure plate that requires more than that force. Also, the spells mentions a few uses. Only "manipulate an object" appear to describe some way to trigger a trap. But "manipulating a pressure plate" is not "pushing a pressure plate".

Answer (score 0):

I would say it can. The specific wording of spell says "it can manipulate an object" Considering any non-magical trap is an 'item', that means mage hand can activate it.

Answer: mage Hand can activate non-magical traps
(If you're a player): Ask your DM/GM for what they would say.

Edit: The exact wording of the spell in the book it is from (I don't remember) says that it says it can "manipulate an object." Among other options it gives you, this one stood out to me. According to the Cambridge Dictionary it means "the act of controlling or moving something using the hands." This means that the Mage Hand can control or move an item. If the trap was an item, such as a tripwire activated trap, the mage hand activate non-magical traps. The reason I would say it can't activate non-magical traps, I would think it would not "sense" the mage hand.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se. Please take the [tour] :) Could you go into more detail about how the manipulation would work?

Comment: About the manipulation - The exact wording of the spell in the book it is from (I don't remember) says that it says it can "manipulate an object." Among other options it gives you, this one stood out to me. According to the Cambridge Dictionary it means "the act of controlling or moving something using the hands." This means that the Mage Hand can control or move an item. If the trap was an item, such as a tripwire activated trap, the mage hand activate non-magical traps. The reason I would say it can't activate non-magical traps, I would think it would not "sense" the mage hand.

Comment: It would be useful to add that to your answer :)